# Rectangular to cylindrical coordinates with volume material

Tags: shaders, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to create a volume material which consists of several rings that pulse outwards. I have a solution with a cylinder. It consists of a wave texture of rings along the x axis, where the phase is driven by frame time.

[image]

I'd like to wrap this in a torus shape. I have tried using rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates as an input for the vector of the wave texture, but can't seem to get cylinder wrapped in torus.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need to take into account the torus major radius to do that.

[image]

The idea is to take a slice of the torus and calculate wave input coordinates from the slice center point.

[image]

Which can be done with the following:

[image]

Get X Y component to have the axis to the center point.

Normalize it and scale by the major radius of the torus to obtain the slice center point.

Use two dot products to have X along Z and Y along the axis to the center point.

Use the wave and use Z axis for it as we calculated X, Y above.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think about using the vector scale and subtracting it from the original object coords to make a new coordinate system. In my head, the second coord system is X pointing out in the direction of the major radius, then y pointing up, and z pointing along the curve of the torus. Thank you! Now I can stretch gradient textures into toruses as well! And scale the x and y components!

I do see cylindrical coordinates here... I see a r, theta, z. I'll see if a similar result can be done using arctan rather than vectors. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach would be to use distance-from-circle, Pythagoras all the way.

This group returns the 3D distance from an XY circle of radius `radius` centered on 0 in your given vector-space:

[image]

The distance-function, if put through a less-than threshold, yields a volumetric torus. It could be used pretty much the same way as your distance-from-line.

Here with some bells and whistles, *Ping-Pong*-ing the distance to give bands in the torus volume, varying the colour with distance, offsetting 0 to animate the bands:

[image]

for this kind of result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ooops, probably backwards, for you.. reverse keyframes in the 'Add' node...